# How to pass an item from ng-repeat to a controller created/loaded by ng-include?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat that loads an ng-include.   I'd like to have a separate controller inside the view that the ng-include loads.

But I'm having trouble accessing the item from ng-repeat in that controller.  I tried something like this, and it fails.

How do I get at `result` inside of `SubController`?

```
    <div ng-repeat="result in results">
            <div class="box" ng-include="view/someinclude.html"></div>
    </div>
```

view/someinclude.html:

```
<div ng-controller="SubController">
     ...
</div>
```

controller js:

```
angular.module('SubController', [])
    .controller('SubController', ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {
            //fails
            console.log($scope.result);
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your scopes are a part of the same module, or they they're different include one in the other, if that's not the problem then it'll be something outside what you've shown, as something like this:

```
angular.module("app").controller.(testController", ["$scope", function($scope){
     console.log($scope.x)
}])
```

with:

```
<div ng-repeat = "x in [1,2]">
        <div ng-include = "'./views/vew.test.html'">
        </div>
</div>
```

and in vew.test.html:

```
<div ng-controller = "testController">
    {{x}}
</div>
```

Will wack 1 and 2 on the screen and in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the same module:

```
angular.module('SubController').controller('SubController', function() {...});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$parent.result` instead of `$scope.result` inside your controller as ng-include creates a new scope of its own that [prototypically inherits](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-include) from its parent scope.